# Python 3 - Getting multiple inputs for a variable

Tags: python, variables, python-3.x, input

I'm trying to get the user to be able to input several values into the cash register. When they are done, all they have to type in is -1 and it won't request any more values to be input. Once this is done, the program adds up the total of the numbers input, and then spits them out in a message as netPrice. grossPrice however adds them up but adds 10% GST to the end value. I've had no experience with raw_input or continuing variables, and searching here I found some information that I attempted to apply to the code, however failed for me.

```
#x = continued input ("Enter in net price of items for the cash register: ")
#if x -1:
#   stop;
#netPrice = x
#grossPrice = netPrice + (0.1 * netPrice)

#print ("The net price of all items is: $",netPrice)
#print ("The gross price of all items (this includes GST) is: $",grossPrice)

x = raw_input("Enter in net price of items for the cash register: ")
if x >=-1:
    stop;
netPrice = x
grossPrice = netPrice + (0.1 * netPrice)

print ("The net price of all items is: $",netPrice)
print ("The gross price of all items (this includes GST) is: $",grossPrice)
```

Comment: In what way did it fail? What did it do and what did you expect it to do?

Comment: @TimCastelijns I expected it to return netPrice, and for raw_input to continue processing numbers input by the user. Although it seemed my version of Python had raw_input removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something as follows:

```
values = []

while True:
    x = float(input('Enter in net price of items for the cash register: '))
    if x == -1:
        break
    values.append(x)

print ("The net price of all items is: " + str(sum(values)))
```

Comment: I'm guessing the Python version I'm using has eliminated raw_input. Damn.

Comment: @Reecety, In that case, just use `input`

Comment: What happens if user enters a non-float value?